# Openx set multiple value to the source parameter

Tags: parameters, openx

Is there a way to set a multiple value to the source parameter on OpenX with a separator like source=cat1,cat2 or source=cat1|cat2 or whatever separator?

My goal is to use channel and be able to have a single page validating many channels.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it by myself. Channels allows to match REGEXP so i could pass anything i want to the parameter as long as i'm able to preg match it after.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to concat the parameters by a separator, i.e. **_** and add it as prefix and postfix too: ...&**source=_foo_bar_**&...

Now you're able to target with "**Site:Source contains**", i.e. contains "**_*foo*_**" which is easier to use as a REGEX.